# Find the series having sum equal to x and product equal to y

Tags: sequences-and-series, power-series, real-numbers

Recently on programming platform, I came across this problem, And couldn't solve it.
Problem:
Given two values $x$ and $y$, where $x$ is the sum of the series and $y$ is the product of series. We have to find the series with the minimum size possible. Also series could can contain any real number.
I am interested to know that which mathematics concept is this.

Comment: the smallest series is 2+2=2*2, the next 1+2+3=1*2*3, I do not think this is any mathematical concept.

Comment: Welcome to Math SE. For the series containing only non-negative real numbers, where you know how many terms the series has, you could try using the [Inequality of arithmetic and geometric means](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inequality_of_arithmetic_and_geometric_means).